# Number not increasing with each refresh of page

Tags: php

What I am trying to do every time the page is refreshed `$insertedBookings` should be adding how many were entered so that it becomes a total however its still staying at `6` there is a total of `11` items to be entered.

**Code Updated:**

```
    $insertedBookings = 0;
    foreach($json->data as $row)
        {
        if (!in_array($row->guestEmail, $emails) && date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row->startDate)) == date('Y-m-d'))
            {
$insertedBookings ++;

            $guests[] = array(
                'FirstName' => $row->guestFirstName,
                'LastName' => $row->guestLastName,
                'email' => $row->guestEmail,
                'country' => $row->guestCountry,
                'check-in_date' => $row->startDate,
                'check-out_date' => $row->endDate,
            );
            $emails[] = $row->guestEmail;
            }
        }

    // Insert to IF HERE

    if (!isset($_SESSION["totalInsertedBookings"]))
        {
        $_SESSION["totalInsertedBookings"] = $insertedBookings;
        }

    $currentInsertedBooking = $_SESSION["totalInsertedBookings"];

**Code:**  

    $insertedBookings = 0;
    foreach($json->data as $row)
        {
        if (!in_array($row->guestEmail, $emails) && date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row->startDate)) == date('Y-m-d'))
            {
            $guests[] = array(
                'FirstName' => $row->guestFirstName,
                'LastName' => $row->guestLastName,
                'email' => $row->guestEmail,
                'country' => $row->guestCountry,
                'check-in_date' => $row->startDate,
                'check-out_date' => $row->endDate,
            );
            $emails[] = $row->guestEmail;
            $insertedBookings = count($guests);
            }
        }

    // Insert to IF HERE

    if (!isset($_SESSION["totalInsertedBookings"]))
        {
        $_SESSION["totalInsertedBookings"] = $insertedBookings;
        }

    $currentInsertedBooking = $_SESSION["totalInsertedBookings"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because count($guests) is counting the number of elements in the $guests array which is 6 (FirstName, LastName, etc.).

Comment: ahh thanks,  How can I make it so it counts how many objects?

Comment: Count how many times it goes through the loop.
$counter = 0; //do this before your foreach loop.

foreach (....) {
   $counter++;
}

Comment: Thanks,  I have moved it above the $guest array however I am still getting 6 :)

Comment: What does $json->data contain? Have you printed that out to see that it has the data you're looking for? That might be where the problem is now.